# VS Code: Cannot see Git in Project Manager

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed VS Code on two computers. Then I downloaded the Git Extension Pack. And on one computer I don't see the Git tab in Project Manager, and on the other computer it showed up without any problems... Do any of you know how to solve this problem?

Update1:
I noticed that the git tab shows even if I unsinstall the Git Extension Pack. And the Project manager and his tabs are depend on a different extension "Project Manager" v 12.6.0. I reinstalled this many times and  it did not help. I also noticed that "Project Manager" was in the Git Extension Pack.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you press the right mouse button in the Project Manager a box should open where you can select git to be shown.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a choice of "Help and feedback" and "Favorites", there is no "git". But on the other computer, "git" is there :/

Comment: I added a photo to show it.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the right extension?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes, please check my update in the description.

Comment: And what about the Git Extension Pack?

Comment: Turned out it can be uninstalled because it depends on extension Project Manager. I tried it on my second computer and it can be uninstalled (the Git Extension Pack). I added new screen.

Comment: I dunno its very unclear for me to see where the problem is. Just try reinstalling everything and check that you really have the same extensions and in the worst case reinstall your vscode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It works for me. Now the git tab is in the Project Manager.